# Detecting map changes using Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Is it possible to delete a vector layer when a user pans or zooms a map? I saw in the documentation that there is a function called [onMapResize](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.onMapResize). Can this also be used to detect a pan change?

I want to delete a point if the map is panned or zoomed and tried using it in the following way (which does not work):

```
map.OpenLayers.vectorLayer.onMapResize(console.log('map was moved'))
//use removeAllFeatures() to remove vector points
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vadim is right. you can do it with registering map moveend and zoomend events.

```
map.events.register("moveend", map, function(){
     var lyr = map.getLayersByName('vectorLayer')[0];
     map.removeLayer(lyr);
});

map.events.register("zoomend", map, function(){
     var lyr = map.getLayersByName('vectorLayer')[0];
     map.removeLayer(lyr);
});
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 5):

See the `map` `events`.  http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.events

You want `moveend` and `zoomend`.